# Is there a way to accelerate date parser on seconds-past-midnight records?

Tags: python, pandas, python-multiprocessing

Suppose that I have the following dataset with date (`str`) in `date_str` column and number of seconds past midnight (`int`) in `seconds_past_midnight` column. I want to parse the datetime based on the combination of these two columns.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

n = 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame({'seconds_past_midnight': np.random.randint(34200, 57601, size=n), 'date_str': ['2015-07-14']*n})

print(df)

          date_str  seconds_past_midnight
0       2015-07-14                  48642
1       2015-07-14                  39170
2       2015-07-14                  43940
3       2015-07-14                  46927
4       2015-07-14                  55376
5       2015-07-14                  35859
6       2015-07-14                  38705
7       2015-07-14                  35932
8       2015-07-14                  36874
9       2015-07-14                  39487
...            ...                    ...
999990  2015-07-14                  54837
999991  2015-07-14                  47146
999992  2015-07-14                  54188
999993  2015-07-14                  54729
999994  2015-07-14                  35574
999995  2015-07-14                  35815
999996  2015-07-14                  38727
999997  2015-07-14                  38374
999998  2015-07-14                  53055
999999  2015-07-14                  43303

[1000000 rows x 2 columns]

print(df.dtypes)

date_str                 object
seconds_past_midnight     int64
dtype: object
```

The most straightforward way I can think of is to construct `pd.Timedelta` based on those number of seconds and add them to the date object, but that's essentially a row-wise for loop when using `pd.Timedelta` to do the conversion, which is very slow.

```
%time df.apply(lambda row: pd.to_datetime(row.date_str) + pd.Timedelta(row.seconds_past_midnight, 's'), axis=1)


CPU times: user 2min 5s, sys: 311 ms, total: 2min 5s
Wall time: 2min 5s
```

So I am wondering whether there is a way to accelerate this process? maybe some vectorized functions on datetime object that I was not aware of? I think one way to slightly improve the speed is to use `multiprocessing` module, and maybe I could expect 4-6 time faster on a 8-core PC. Also, because I invoke python function in the `apply`, cython or jit does not help in this case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both `pd.to_datetime` and `pd.to_timedelta` are already vectorized.

```
In [13]: np.random.seed(1234)

In [14]: df = pd.DataFrame({'seconds_past_midnight': np.random.randint(34200, 57601, size=n), 'date_str': ['2015-07-14']*n})

In [15]: df.head()
Out[15]: 
     date_str  seconds_past_midnight
0  2015-07-14                  35518
1  2015-07-14                  51248
2  2015-07-14                  56721
3  2015-07-14                  57417
4  2015-07-14                  42671

In [16]: df.info()
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
Int64Index: 1000000 entries, 0 to 999999
Data columns (total 2 columns):
date_str                 1000000 non-null object
seconds_past_midnight    1000000 non-null int64
dtypes: int64(1), object(1)
memory usage: 22.9+ MB

In [17]: (pd.to_datetime(df['date_str']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['seconds_past_midnight'],unit='s')).head()
Out[17]: 
0   2015-07-14 09:51:58
1   2015-07-14 14:14:08
2   2015-07-14 15:45:21
3   2015-07-14 15:56:57
4   2015-07-14 11:51:11
dtype: datetime64[ns]

In [18]: %timeit pd.to_datetime(df['date_str']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['seconds_past_midnight'],unit='s')        
10 loops, best of 3: 187 ms per loop
```

This is with current master which has serveral perf improvements. In 0.16.2 this is 2x slower.

Comment: I forgot the `pd.to_timedelta()`. Thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 2):

```
dates = pd.to_datetime(df.date_str) + pd.to_timedelta(df.seconds_past_midnight, unit='s')
```

Comment: Uhh, I missed `pd.to_timedelta()`. Thank you so much! :-)

Answer (score 1):

You could also do the addition with [NumPy datetime64's and timedelta64's](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.datetime.html):

```
(np.array(df['date_str'], '<M8[D]') + 
np.array(df['seconds_past_midnight'], dtype='<m8[s]'))
```

---

For example,

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(1234)

n = 1000000
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'seconds_past_midnight': np.random.randint(34200, 57601, size=n), 
    'date_str': ['2015-07-14']*n})
```

Including assignment to a DataFrame:

```
In [4]: pd.__version__
Out[6]: u'0.16.2+175.g5a9a9da'

In [7]: %timeit df['date'] = np.array(df['date_str'], '<M8[D]')+np.array(df['seconds_past_midnight'], dtype='<m8[s]')
10 loops, best of 3: 94.6 ms per loop

In [8]: %timeit df['date2'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_str']) + pd.to_timedelta(df['seconds_past_midnight'],unit='s')  
10 loops, best of 3: 188 ms per loop

In [12]: df['date'].equals(df['date2'])
Out[12]: True
```

(Without assignment to a DataFrame, the datetime64/timedelta64 sum returns a NumPy array, while the `to_datetime/to_timedelta` sum returns a Pandas Series so comparing these would be an apples-to-oranges comparison.)

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe parse it strptime("%Y-%m-%d %f"), %f is technically micro seconds, don't know if this helps?